# Porque o meu script PHP somente me retorna Resource id #4?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando pegar somente o nome de uma coluna de uma tabela do banco de dados, e ele sempre me retorna somente o Resource id #4, vou enviar uma parte do meu código.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ("Erro ao conectar!");
    mysql_select_db('agenda') or die ("Erro ao conectar!");
?>

<?php
   $iid = $_GET['id'];
   //echo $iid;
   $nomepessoa = "SELECT nome FROM pessoa WHERE id = $iid";

   $queryy = mysql_query($nomepessoa);

   echo $queryy;

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_query()` retorna um resource ou um false em caso de erro. Para extrair a informação dele é necessário utilizar a `mysql_fetch_assoc()` ou outro sabor de retorno. Três coisas importantes,

- As funções mysql_* já foram removidas do php7 então é melhor utilizar o PDO ou MySQLi.
- `mysql_fetch_assoc()` ou `mysql_fetch_array()` retornam apenas uma linha, caso queira retorna outras é necessário um while.
- Dê nomes significativos as suas variáveis.

Seu código corrigido deve ficar dessa forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT nome FROM pessoa WHERE id =" .mysql_real_escape_string($iid);
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$pessoa = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $pessoa['nome'];
```

Comment: Só complementando, tem que passar o parametro na função `mysql_fetch_assoc ( resource $result )`

Comment: @JefersonAssis, obrigado, corrigido.

Comment: Sim funcionou corretamente, muito obrigado!
E obrigado pelas dicas rray.